# Subquery in SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to accomplish something like:

```
,sell = (select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (0, 2))
,buy =  (select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (4))
,SUM(sell - buy)  AS current_balance --Invalid column name
```

...which gives back an error on the last row as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was, if you are selecting a column and giving it an alias in select statement, you cannot use that alias as column in the same select statement

Try this:-

```
,sell = (select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (0, 2))
,buy =  (select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (4))
,SUM((select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (0, 2))
- (select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (4)))
```

Comment: @India.Rocket : You could have explain what modification you have done in the existing query.

Comment: Actually, in SSRS it returns:
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @Wanderer done. Thanks for pointing that out. Forgot to do that

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer by `India.Rocket`:

The given suggestion is very susceptible to changes, you could also fix this by using a subquery like the following:

```
select sell, buy, sell - buy AS current_balance
from (
    select sell = sum(select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (0, 2))
        , buy =  sum(select tr.money_value from dpdata.DP_Transaction tr where tr.transaction_type IN (4))
) as Subquery
```

This way when you change the definiton of `sell` or `buy` you cannot forget to change the definition of `current_balance` as well to prevent any differences.